# How can I get Clang colors to work in boost-bjam?

Tags: c++, boost, clang, bjam

`b2 release link=static toolset=clang` works, but it does not show the nice colors that I find useful in clang's output.

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer:** this is not an answer solving your problem, but it takes too much space to put this in a comment.

Here's a brief Holmesian elimination process. First, according to the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#cl_diagnostics), color is enabled only when a color-capable terminal is detected. And secondly, according to the [Boost.Jam documentation](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/faq/envar.html), all environment variables are automatically imported into its built-in `.ENVIRON` module. Finally, you do indeed have a color-capable terminal. Yet it does not work. Even forcing the issue with an explicit Clang command line argument

```
./b2 install --toolset=clang --cxxflag=-fcolor-diagnostics
```

fails to display colored diagnostics. My only conclusion is that somehow `b2` does not launch its build inside a color coded terminal. Upon further digging based on your comments, I found a [related problem on another build system](https://github.com/martine/ninja/issues/174):

> The reason for this is that ninja sets subprocess stdout/stderr to a
>   pipe (Subprocess::Start(), subprocess.cc), and clang checks if
>   StandardErrHasColors() (tools/clang/lib/Driver/Tools.cpp), which is
>   false if !isatty(2) (lib/Support/Unix/Process.inc).
>
> I looked around a bit, and the way to do this seems to be to call
>   fork_pty() to run the child in a pseudo terminal. I don't know if this
>   would impact subprocess creation time, and if opening ~4000 pseudo
>   ttys (a chrome build at -j10000) is considered good form.
>
> (It's possible to force clang to always emit color escaped codes using
>   "-Xclang -fcolor-diagnostics", but that's pretty hacky. make doesn't
>   seem to override stderr on unix as far as I can tell,
>   child_execute_job() in job.c)

**Conclusion**: you might have to dig into the `b2` internals to see if there is some output redirection taking place that prevents the color-coding. Alternatively, you could ask on the [Boost.Build mailinglist](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/). Hopefully this helps you along a bit further.

**Update**: there is a [long standing ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3508) on the Boost SVN site that deals with this.

Comment: Thanks, but I knew this part. $TERM is xterm-256color. Invoking clang from command line displays colors. I am not able to use the SCons question directly. I guess I need to add something to user-config.jam but I don't know what.

Comment: @HumbleDebugger if you `echo` your `TERM` variable from inside your `user-config.jam`, what output do you get?

Comment: @HumbleDebugger I'm not at a build machine right now, but could you try `b2 -s"TERM=xterm-256color"` followed by your other build arguments?

Comment: @HumbleDebugger I did some more digging and rewrote my findings. Sorry to say there is no solution. I am keeping this answer for future reference.

Comment: @HumbleDebugger Found an ticket on the Boost SVN site, see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I did not think it would go this deep.

Comment: @TemplateRex After I added <cflags>-fcolor-diagnostics to Jamfile I get coloured output. Maybe it has been fixed since your original comment? I am using Boost.Build 2014.03-svn in the KDE Konsole terminal emulator.

Comment: @JanŠimek Glad to hear it got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Seems the core issue was somehow solved, but there's a little more explaining to be done regarding it.

If you want colors, you can use this in `user-config.jam`:

```
using clang : : : <compileflags>-fcolor-diagnostics ;
```

However, my personal preference is to handle this in my Jamroot by using project requirements so others don't need to deal with it:

```
project my_project : requirements
  <toolset>clang:<cflags>-fcolor-diagnostics
  <toolset>clang:<cxxflags>-fcolor-diagnostics
;
```